# $.mobile.changePage not working in Chrome & Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, jquery-mobile, safari

I am trying to display a dialogbox with jQuery Mobile. The code is as follows

```
if(condition){
  setTimeout(function(){
    $.mobile.changePage('#myDiv',{transition:'pop', role: 'dialog'});
  },100);
}
```

I also have the following code to generate the content of that dialogbox dynamically

```
$('#myDiv').on('pageshow', function(){
  // do custom operation
});
```

It is working perfectly in Fireforx and IE. But in chrome and safari, the dialogbox appears then disappears within few seconds.

I have been banging my head on this for a day already. Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

EDIT: I think it will be great if I state the DOM structure. So here I go...

```
<html>
<head>...</head>
<body>
 <div data-role="page" id="startPage">
  ...
  <script>
   $('#startPage').on('pageinit', function(){
    // Do some stuff
    if(condition){
     setTimeout(function(){
      $.mobile.changePage('#myDiv', {transition: 'pop', role: 'dialog'});
     }, 100);
    }
   });
  </script>
 </div>
 <div data-role="dialog" id="myDiv">
  ...
  <script>
   $('#myDiv').on('pageshow', function(){
    // do custom operation
   });
  </script>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: is it getting populated with changehash, as per the documentation where you have `'#myDiv'` should be a path of the page.

Comment: Do you place the dialog div outside page div, making `<body>` parent of the div?

Comment: @Jai, I guess my question was confusing without a snapshot of the DOM. So I have modified my question. Thanx

Comment: @mahfuz01 I am also facing the same problem what you faced. Can you tell me how you solved the problem. Page gets disappear in chrome and in firefox it is working fine.

Comment: Hi @Royal, to be honest, I forgot how I resolved this issue. But I have 2 suggestions for you. #1: Check the CSS of the div for z-index (Chrome renders CSS differently than FF) #2: Take out the in-line scripts and place them at the bottom just before the closing body tag. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try pulling all the script outside of the page DIVs and putting it right before the closing body tag.  Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/Cje6D/).  This works for me in Chrome and Safari.

```
<div data-role="page" id="startPage">
  <div data-role="header"><h1>Page</h1></div>
</div>

<div data-role="dialog" id="myDiv">
  <div data-role="header"><h1>Dialog</h1></div>
  <div data-role="content">
    <span id="dynamicContent"></span>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
var condition = true;   
$('#startPage').on('pageinit', function(){
  if(condition){
   setTimeout(function(){
    $.mobile.changePage('#myDiv', {transition: 'pop', role: 'dialog'});
   }, 100);
  }
});

$('#myDiv').on('pageshow', function(){
  $('#dynamicContent').html('Here is some dynamic content!');
});
</script>
```